# Given a string how to randomly transpose 2 of their letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list-comprehension

Given a string:

```
s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

How can I randomly select a token, swap two letters from that token and return the string with the modified token? For example `(*)`:

```
The quick brown fxo jumps over the lazy dog
```

In the above example the token `fox` was selected randomly and two characters were swapped.

So far I tried to:

```
def swap_letters(string):
    s = list(string)
    s[0], s[len(s)-1] = s[len(s)-1].upper(), s[0].lower()
    string = ''.join(s)
    return string    


def foo(a_string):
    a_string_lis = a_string.split()
    token = random.choice(a_string_lis)
    return swap_letters(token)
```

However, I am getting more than 2 letters transposed and I dont know how to keep the order of the tokens inside the strings. Any idea of how to get `(*)` in a more pythonic way?

Comment: What is `(*) ` suppose to mean?

Comment: The expected output @RedCricket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import random
random.seed(42)

s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'


def transpose(text, number=2):

    # select random token
    tokens = text.split()
    token_pos = random.choice(range(len(tokens)))

    # select random positions in token
    positions = random.sample(range(len(tokens[token_pos])), number)

    # swap the positions
    l = list(tokens[token_pos])
    for first, second in zip(positions[::2], positions[1::2]):
        l[first], l[second] = l[second], l[first]

    # replace original tokens with swapped
    tokens[token_pos] = ''.join(l)

    # return text with the swapped token
    return ' '.join(tokens)


result = transpose(s)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
The iuqck brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**UPDATE**

For strings of length `1` the above code fails, something like this should fix it:

```
def transpose(text, number=2):

    # select random token
    tokens = text.split()
    positions = list(i for i, e in enumerate(tokens) if len(e) > 1)

    if positions:

        token_pos = random.choice(positions)

        # select random positions in token
        positions = random.sample(range(len(tokens[token_pos])), number)

        # swap the positions
        l = list(tokens[token_pos])
        for first, second in zip(positions[::2], positions[1::2]):
            l[first], l[second] = l[second], l[first]

        # replace original tokens with swapped
        tokens[token_pos] = ''.join(l)

    # return text with the swapped token
    return ' '.join(tokens)
```

Comment: Could use `token_pos = random.randrange(len(tokens))` there

Comment: I got ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative

Comment: Could you provide the string for the error? Is `number` larger than the number of words (tokens)?

Comment: Its difficult because im running this in a large number of sentences, however: with `hi` I got that

Comment: It works for me in `hi`, what number did you pass? If I pass 3 as the number it fails. Note that the functions expects that number is even. Also 3 is larger than the length of hi, so you cannot sample 3 elements from a population of 2 elements.

Comment: is there any way of fixing for number `3`?

Comment: What will be the expected output for `hi` with length `3`. Also how do you swap 3 elements? It could be fixed quickly for any even number, does that help?

Comment: For example for `ana` it could be fixed as `aan`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185484/discussion-between-daniel-mesejo-and-anon).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `str.replace` method:

```
def swap_letters(string):
    s = list(string)
    s[0], s[len(s)-1] = s[len(s)-1], s[0]
    string = ''.join(s)
    return string

def foo(a_string):
    a_string_lis = a_string.split()
    token = random.choice(a_string_lis)
    return a_string.replace(token, swap_letters(token))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    def swap_letters(string,pos,string1):
        s = list(string)
        s[len(s)-1], s[len(s)-2] = s[len(s)-2], s[len(s)-1].lower()
        string = ''.join(s)
        string1[pos[0]]=string
        s1= ' '.join(string1)
        return s1    
    def foo(a_string):
        a_string_lis = a_string.split()
        print(a_string_lis)
        token = random.choice(a_string_lis)
        pos=[i for i in range(len(a_string_lis)) if a_string_lis[i]==token]
        return swap_letters(token,pos,a_string_lis)
    s='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
    print(foo(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
from random import choice, sample


s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'

tokenize = s.split()
token = choice([x for x in tokenize if len(x)>2])  # choose a random word from phrase with at least 2 letters
chosen = sample(token, k=2)                        # choose two random letters word
d = dict(zip(chosen, chosen[::-1]))

new_token = ''
for letter in token:
  if letter in d:
    new_token += d[letter]
    del d[letter]
  else:
    new_token += letter

s = ' '.join([word if word != token else new_token for word in tokenize])
```

which produces:

```
print(s)  # -> The quick brown fox jumps over the lyza dog
#                                                  ||
```

Comment: I got: `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative`

Comment: if the chosen word contains less than two letters, it can happen. You can fix this by replacing `token = choice(tokenize)` with `token = choice([x for x in tokenize if len(x)>2])`